# Nodejs socket.io socket property becomes null

Tags: node.js, socket.io

So I am trying to retrieve all the sockets connected to a room. However what i noticed was that adding properties to the sockets such as `socket.username` become undefined when accessed later on in my server script. Therefore I get an error like so `TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined`. I am using version 1.3.3 of the module.

here is the code that triggers the error

```
function clientsInRoom(room){
   var clients = [];
   console.log(io.sockets.adapter.rooms[room].length); // This prints out the correct number
   for(var cliSocket in  io.sockets.adapter.rooms[room] ){
        clients.push(io.sockets.connected[cliSocket].username); // Causes exception
   }
  return clients;
}

io.on('connection', function(socket){
   socket.on('adduser', function(username,room){
        // store the room name in the socket session for this client
        socket.room = room;
        // store the username in the socket session for this client
        socket.username = username;
        // Check if they already exist in room
        if(clientExists(username,room) == false){
            //Tell user they have joined new room
            socket.emit('updatechat','you have connected to '+ room);
            //echo to room that a person has connected to their room
            socket.broadcast.to(socket.room).emit('updatechat', username + ' has joined this room','con');
        }
        // send client to the room
        socket.join(socket.room);
        //Update online lists client side
        io.sockets.in(socket.room).emit('updatePeople', clientsInRoom(socket.room));

   });
});
```

If anyone could shed some light on this issue as it has been driving me insane, would be greatly appreciatd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're iterating over keys of `io.sockets.adapter.rooms`. Then using those keys to access `io.sockets.connected`. What you get out of `io.sockets.connected` is undefined, not your saved username.

Check this iteration code, this is where the problem is.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I already established that the iteration is where my problem lies. My question is rather why it is returning undefined, I am clearly assigning the properties of username and room to my socket. Is there an internal problem with the library ?

Comment: You misunderstand. Properties aren't undefined. This is undefined: `io.sockets.connected[cliSocket]`. Read your error message more carefully.

Comment: I see what you mean, it is has nothing to do with the username or any property since the root object is undefined which is what that line is attempting to return. But this leads me to believe there was a problem prior to the iteration where the socket did not get registered ? hence why it is undefined. I don't have much experience with node hence why I am asking to know if I have missed any crucial steps or am doing something which is invalid. Based on my research that should work but still ... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There were discrepancies between my node modules that caused this problem. Manually copying the modules from an older release resolved the issue